# Insert a Context menu Item to Explorer and pass the Full File Name when Context Menu item is Clicked

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shell, contextmenu

I want to add a context menu item to the windows explorer context menu for all "jpg" files .The name of the context menu item will be 'process JPEG' when the user clicks this,a main executable will be invoked.The problem is i have already created the main c# executable and its not run only via context menu it can be run independently.I want to pass the file name or file-names which the user select and clicks the context menu command and to the main executable,so that the main executable will be able to get the files using some method and process those.I have done the following to integrate the context menu-Please help me out

```
public static void Register(
            string fileType, string shellKeyName, 
            string menuText, string menuCommand)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuText) && 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuCommand));

            // create full path to registry location
            string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

            // add context menu to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(regPath))
            {
                key.SetValue(null, menuText);
            }

            // add command that is invoked to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
                string.Format(@"{0}\command", regPath)))
            {               
                key.SetValue(null, menuCommand);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To register a verb for a [file type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on older versions of Windows you would:

1. Get the [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In your case, read the default value under `HKCR\.jpg` (This normally gives you something like `jpgfile`)
2. Write your verb command under `HKCR\%ProgId%\shell\%YourVerb%\command`

Starting with XP you can register supplemental verbs under SystemFileAssociations without having control of the ProgID:

1. Write your verb command under `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\shell\%YourVerb%\command`

The verb command is usually `"c:\full\path\to\yourapp.exe" "%1"` and %1 is replaced with the filename by windows. Your application has to parse the commandline.

To properly support opening several files at the same time it might be a good idea to use [DDE or IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#invoking_verbs) (Or [IExecuteCommand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/12/9977246.aspx) on Win7+)

Comment: I have successfully passed the name of a single file to main application,But if i select multiple files the application is invoked multiple times.How can i avoid this.

Comment: @techno: DDE, IDropTarget, IExecuteCommand or some form of custom inter process communication where the additional processes communicate with the initial process and have it open the file...

Comment: Thanks.Can you please give me an example to do this with DDE

Comment: @techno: DDE is a deprecated technology, unless you are supporting < WinXP you should really consider using something else. Either way, it is not something I can help you with in a comment on SO...